# how to compare ibutton text with integer?

Tags: android

in my code i  compare button.gettext with int value both are eqyal but its not print Toast message.    not comparing two values help me....

```
        public static int mDay;
        Button e01;

        public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];

           e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);

         if(e01.getText().toString().equals(mDay))
    {
        e01.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBBFF"));

    Toast.makeText(this, "Button2 text equals!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



          //// in debug mode both gives value 29
               e01.getText().toString() =29
               mDay=29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an integer with a string.. You need to convert the int to a string

```
int a = 29;
String b = "29";
System.out.println(b.equals(a));
//prints false
System.out.println(b.equals(String.valueOf(a)));
//prints true
```

So essentially your if should be like that:

```
if(e01.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(mDay))
```

Answer (score 1):

test this condition

```
Integer.parseInt(e01.getText().toString()) == mDay
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
if(Integer.parseInt(e01) == mDay)